# How do I find a replacement for this light fixture enclosure?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I recently moved into a new place and I was able to pull off the glass enclosure attached to this light fixture:

[image]

However, when I pulled it off a second time, the enclosure shattered in my hands from the pressure of pulling. I've tried searching for light fixtures but it's almost impossible to find one that attaches in the same way as this one does. How can I find a replacement? Also interested in knowing how to take the enclosure off again in the future without shattering it.

Comment: Replace the whole fixture.  It will take 5 minutes.

Comment: That's definitely an option, but I'd prefer to have it match the other fixtures. Otherwise I'd need to replace every single fixture.

Comment: How many of them are there?

Comment: How many are there? I doesn't seem stupid to replace things that explode in your face.

Comment: I had assumed it exploded in my face because I was using it wrong, but you make a solid point.

Comment: Buying old fixture glass is difficult.  Thrift stores, antique stores etc. Even then when you find the one you looking for, many times it's  not exactly identical but only close, because it came from say a slightly different year than the original

Comment: Yeah. I think it's worth the investment to get new fixtures that won't blow up on me. Thanks.

Comment: your local Re-store may also have it. And you can buy replacement glass "domes" for the diameter and depth you may need even at a big box store or a local lighting supplier, but do not expect to get an exact match,

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you could take the fixture down, examine all markings and google search any words or numbers you find on them.

If that doesn't work, and you have a picture of it or can take one of another similar fixture, you could use [TinEye](https://www.tineye.com/) to find a similar photo and hope that it's on a product listing page.

Replacing a light fixture however, is pretty easy.  I recommend buying spare globes for any glass fixtures and keeping them in a safe place.